# Understanding composition of vector fields

Tags: differential-geometry

I've finished a first course on differential geometry and I still find it confusing on how to compose/multiply two vector fields.

Let's assume that $X$ and $Y$ are two vector fields on a smooth manifold. Then my understanding of $XY$ is that:
$$XY f (p)=X_p (Y f).$$
Therefore if $X$ and $Y$ belong to the Lie algebra of a group $G$, then
$$XY f(g)=X_g(Yf)=\frac{d}{dt} (Yf)(g\exp tX_e)|_{t=0}=
\frac{d}{dt}\frac{d}{ds} f(g\exp tX_e\exp sY_e)|_{s=0}|_{t=0}.$$

Does this sound OK so far? Now I want to set $X=Y$ to get
$$XX f(g)=
\frac{d}{dt}\frac{d}{ds} f(g\exp (t+s)X_e)|_{s=0}|_{t=0}.$$
However, the expression that I have in my notes for $XX$ is
$$XX f(g)=
\frac{d^2}{dt^2}f(g\exp (t)X_e)|_{t=0}.$$

Are these two expressions the same?!

Comment: Yes. Those are two different ways of taking the second derivative of something. Can you prove the corresponding fact for just ordinary functions of one variable?

Comment: What leads you to believe they aren't?

Comment: @Qiaochu Ah, stupid me! This is just $\frac{d^2}{dt^2}h(t)|_{t=0}=\frac{d}{dt}\frac{d}{ds}h(t+s)|_{s=0}|_{t=0}$ (chain rule). Thanks! Could I do my interpretation of $XX$ in a way to avoid the extra variable $s$ from the beginning or my thought process is OK?